# org.springframework.core.NestedIOException when have migrated to Spring Boot 3.1.0, Spring 6.0.0 and Java 17

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-17

The application worked well on Spring Boot 3.1.0 and Java 17, but whn was migrated to Spring 6.0.0 with such modules upgrated, isnt started with below error:

```
implementation 'org.springframework:spring-core:6.0.0'
implementation 'org.springframework:spring-beans:6.0.0'
implementation 'org.springframework:spring-expression:6.0.0'
implementation 'org.springframework:spring-webflux:6.0.0'
implementation 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:6.0.0'
implementation 'org.springframework:spring-web:6.0.0'
```

and the logs output is:

```
2023-06-10 23:17:34.892 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/NestedIOException
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:312)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:236)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:280)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:96)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:707)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:533)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:405)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:140)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:212)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:74)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:80)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:345)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at rf.dom.billing.ap.Application.main(Application.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 25 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Spring Boot 3.1.0 depends on Spring Framework 6.0.9 by default. What are you trying to do by downgrading the Spring Framework version to 6.0.0? See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.1.0/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix.dependency-versions

Comment: The fact that you are using Spring Boot and have tons of individual dependencies added makes me wonder what you added more. Basically don't do this as this will lead to incompatible combinations of jars/modules. Instead just use the Spring Boot Starters and not individual dependencies.

Comment: @M.Deinum springboot idea is broken when developer have to avoid vulnerable jars. There are no trivy-proven spring-boot releases, so I have to go through the trivy results list and increase the version numbers of the inidividual devs

Comment: @M.Deinum how I can know what particular incompablitiy breaks the build? The stacktrace isn't informative

Comment: No you shouldn't increase the version of the individual dependencies you should increase the version of the library. Don't mix jars from different versions of a framework as that is trouble waiting to happen (and you asking a question again about why version x.y.1 doesn't work with x.y.2, because it wasn't meant to work in that combo).  With Spring Boot this is actually pretty easy as for all managed dependencies you can simply override the version and not indivudal dependencies! Which is the recommended **and** documented way.

Comment: how can i do it, if vulnerabilities scanner point me to individual dependencies and it almost impossible to know the library version based on that; moreover, to avoit scanner issues, it may require to use different ranges of the versions, since differenv vulnerabilities reside in the different version numbers.

Comment: @Eljah If you don't trust the Spring developers to do a decent job managing vulnerabilities in their product, you probably should refrain from using it.

Comment: @anothernode as a normal worker I do what I was said in terms "remove trivy scans from your app" and as a normal developer I do trust Spring developers. Not all tasks are intended on the resolving the real problems. So I personally always do what some other people told to do, not what I consider right. Sorry for that sad truth.

Answer (score 2):

Hey I also got it and solved it updating this dependency to this version.

```
implementation('org.springframework:spring-context:6.0.11')
```